# groovy config slurper add new structure

Tags: groovy

was looking to rewrite a groovy config property file with a more deeply  nested set of variables 0 see below. This looks typical to me but i cannot find a way to do this :}

```
window {
    width=400
    height=240
}
```

tried property notation like window.width=400 but it does not get written in {} brackets

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? What do you have? What do you want? What have you tried? And how did that fail?  Not sure I get the question as it stands

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def cfg = '''window {
            |    width = 400
            |    height = 240
            |}'''.stripMargin()

def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse( cfg )

assert config.window.width == 400
```

Maybe if you could explain a bit more what you mean, you could get a more accurate answer? ;-)